# Unable to style <li> element text with custom bullet

Tags: css

I have styled my `<ul>` list with custom bullet as shown below.

The problem is that I want the text to be displayed as in the image below:

[image]

So, basically, the overflowing text shouldnt be right below the bullet. I tried the solutions available here on SO but it didnt work in my case.

```css
ul{
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-left: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

ul li {
  list-style: none;
  list-style-position: inside;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 1em;
}

ul li:before {
  content: '\25A0';
  color: #3023AE;
  line-height: 0;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding-bottom: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Tissue death, a dangerous side effect, often results from stroke</li>
  <li>Four million Americans are suffering from the after effects of stroke</li>
  <li>Tissue death, a dangerous side effect, often results from stroke</li>
</ul>
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use it in this way

```css
    ul{
      width: 300px;
      border: 1px solid black;
      margin-left: 0;
      list-style-type: none;
      padding-left:0px;
    }

    ul li {
      list-style: none;
      position: relative;
      margin-left: 1em;
      display:block;
      background:url('http://i.imgur.com/YR9XMuc.png') no-repeat center left ;
      padding-left:30px;
    }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Tissue death, a dangerous side effect, often results from stroke</li>
  <li>Four million Americans are suffering from the after effects of stroke</li>
  <li>Tissue death, a dangerous side effect, often results from stroke</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thats a pretty nice hack. :D

Answer (score 0):

Just position absolutely the before pseudo element:

```css
ul {
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-left: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}
ul li {
  list-style: none;
  list-style-position: inside;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 1em;
}
ul li:before {
  content: '\25A0';
  position: absolute;
  top: 6px;
  left: -15px;
  color: #3023AE;
  line-height: 0;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding-bottom: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Tissue death, a dangerous side effect, often results from stroke</li>
  <li>Four million Americans are suffering from the after effects of stroke</li>
  <li>Tissue death, a dangerous side effect, often results from stroke</li>
</ul>
```